# How to get the key of a value in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Swift 3

I have this social network like twitter and im trying to retrive the user's following list but i'm having some troubles, my idea is to get them so i can use them to then do a for loop and retrive the Posts or Tweets, so something like this

```
self.databaseRef.child("following").child((self.loggedInUser?.uid)!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

                for child in snapshot.children {

                     self.databaseRef.child("Jalas").child((child as AnyObject).key!).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

                        if (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary !=  nil)
                        {
                            self.Jalas.append(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)
                        }

                     }){(error) in

                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }

            }

            self.homeTableView.beginUpdates()
            self.homeTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:0,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

            self.homeTableView.endUpdates()

            self.aivLoading.stopAnimating()

            }
```

and in number of rows in section i'm returning self.Jalas.count but this does nothing. and it throws me an error.

"attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update"

this is my database.

*Jalas = Posts*

```
{
  "Jalas" : {
    "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : {
      "-KbHUnL-RveUQa3MPSWp" : {
        "latitud" : "21.111401000574",
        "longitud" : "-89.6112191677094",
        "text" : "Fiesta en la Anahuac!!! ",
        "timestamp" : "1485295269.30773",
        "ubicacionN" : "Universidad Anáhuac Mayab"
      },
      "-KbI1azr6uFel-5uTZOD" : {
        "latitud" : "Optional(21.018988764483463)",
        "longitud" : "Optional(-89.614319546492695)",
        "text" : "Hola chicos",
        "timestamp" : "1485304393.77929",
        "ubicacionN" : "Calle 53-A 341"
      },
      "-KbNQWxjQhc0Ce_ZQbq9" : {
        "latitud" : "Optional(21.019219877217914)",
        "longitud" : "Optional(-89.614173537203683)",
        "text" : "Hola",
        "timestamp" : "1485394812.83039",
        "ubicacionN" : "Calle 53 341"
      }
    },
    "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : {
      "-KbQOWfUnzY1JiS61J6-" : {
        "latitud" : "Optional(21.111502615883129)",
        "longitud" : "Optional(-89.611767497121221)",
        "text" : "Hola chicos!",
        "timestamp" : "1485444619.10931",
        "ubicacionN" : "Carretera Mérida-Progreso 96"
      }
    }
  },
  "follower" : {
    "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : {
      "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : true
    },
    "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : {
      "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : true
    }
  },
  "following" : {
    "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : {
      "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : true
    },
    "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : {
      "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : true
    }
  },
  "handles" : {
    "jcadmin" : "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2",
    "jcbest" : "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2"
  },
  "user_profiles" : {
    "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : {
      "about" : "Hola Mundo",
      "handle" : "jcbest",
      "name" : "Juan Carlos Estevez Rodriguez",
      "profile_pic" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jalo-267da.appspot.com/o/user_profiles%2FOptional(%22dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2%22)%2Fprofile_pic?alt=media&token=bfc3c516-7849-472c-b7cd-9668965a5dbe"
    },
    "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : {
      "about" : "Hola chicos",
      "handle" : "jcadmin",
      "name" : "Juan Carlos",
      "profile_pic" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jalo-267da.appspot.com/o/user_profiles%2FOptional(%22mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2%22)%2Fprofile_pic?alt=media&token=b741b6c1-0bc5-446d-a1e5-159b21e770d2"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my entire code.

```
//
//  HomeViewController.swift
//  Twitter Clone
//
//  Created by Juan Carlos Estevez on 15/12/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 JC&C. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import SDWebImage
import ReadMoreTextView


class HomeViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    var loggedInUser:AnyObject?
    var loggedInUserData:NSDictionary?
    var listFollowing = [NSDictionary?]()
    var listFollowers = [NSDictionary?]()//store all the followers


    @IBOutlet weak var aivLoading: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var homeTableView: UITableView!

    var defaultImageViewHeightConstraint:CGFloat = 77.0

    var Jalas = [NSDictionary]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.homeTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        //self.homeTableView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 247, green: 247, blue: 247, alpha: 1)

        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.orange

        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.orange

        Evento.sharedInstance.titulo = ""
        Evento.sharedInstance.UbicacionN = nil

        self.loggedInUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser


        self.databaseRef.child("following").child((self.loggedInUser?.uid)!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

                for child in snapshot.children {

                     self.databaseRef.child("Jalas").child((child as AnyObject).key!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

                        //if (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary !=  nil)
                        //{
                            self.Jalas.append(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)
                        //}

                     }

            }



            //self.homeTableView.beginUpdates()
            self.homeTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:0,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

            //self.homeTableView.endUpdates()

            self.aivLoading.stopAnimating()

            }




      /*
        //get the logged in users details
        self.databaseRef.child("user_profiles").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

            //store the logged in users details into the variable
            self.logdInUserData = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            //            print(self.loggedInUserData)



            //get all the Jalas that are made by the user

            self.databaseRef.child("Jalas").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in


                //self.Jalas.append(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)


                self.homeTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:0,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

                self.aivLoading.stopAnimating()

            }){(error) in

                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }
        */

        //when the user has no posts, stop animating the aiv after 5 seconds
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(stopAnimating), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)



        self.homeTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.homeTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140

        /*
        self.databaseRef.child("following").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            self.listFollowing.append(snapshot)
            print(self.listFollowing)

        }) { (error) in

            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


        self.databaseRef.child("followers").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            self.listFollowers.append(snapshot)
            print(self.listFollowers)

        }) { (error) in

            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        */

    }



    @IBAction func NewJalo(_ sender: Any) {
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let welcomeViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "new")

        self.present(welcomeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.orange

        return true
    }

    open func stopAnimating()
    {
        self.aivLoading.stopAnimating()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.Jalas.count

    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        tableView.separatorStyle = .none

        var ubicacion = ""

        let cell: HomeViewTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeViewTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeViewTableViewCell

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        let JaloPost = Jalas[(self.Jalas.count-1) - (indexPath.row)]["text"] as! String

        var HG = 105

        let CHAR = JaloPost.characters.count

        if (CHAR > 30)
        {
            let CH = ((CHAR/30) * 15)
            HG += CH
        }


        if(Jalas[(self.Jalas.count-1) - (indexPath.row)]["picture"] != nil)
        {
            HG += 77
        }


        let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 8, width: Int(self.view.frame.size.width - 20), height: HG))


        whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9])
        whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2

        cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
        cell.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: whiteRoundedView)


        let imageTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTapMediaInTweet(_:)))

        cell.tweetImage.addGestureRecognizer(imageTap)



        if(Jalas[(self.Jalas.count-1) - (indexPath.row)]["ubicacionN"] != nil)
        {
            ubicacion = (Jalas[(self.Jalas.count-1) - (indexPath.row)]["ubicacionN"] as? String)!
        }

        if(Jalas[(self.Jalas.count-1) - (indexPath.row)]["picture"] != nil)
        {
            cell.tweetImage.isHidden = false
            cell.imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = defaultImageViewHeightConstraint

            let picture = Jalas[(self.Jalas.count-1) - (indexPath.row)]["picture"] as! String

            let url = URL(string:picture)
            cell.tweetImage.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            cell.tweetImage.layer.borderWidth = 3
            cell.tweetImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

            cell.tweetImage!.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"twitter")!)

        }
        else
        {
            cell.tweetImage.isHidden = true
            cell.imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
        }
        if (self.loggedInUserData!["profile_pic"] == nil)
        {
            cell.configure(nil,name:self.loggedInUserData!["name"] as! String,handle:self.loggedInUserData!["handle"] as! String,tweet:JaloPost, ubi: ubicacion)
        }else
        {
            cell.configure(self.loggedInUserData!["profile_pic"]! as? String,name:self.loggedInUserData!["name"] as! String,handle:self.loggedInUserData!["handle"] as! String,tweet:JaloPost, ubi: ubicacion)
        }


        return cell
    }


    func didTapMediaInTweet(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {

        let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
        let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)

        newImageView.frame = self.view.frame

        newImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self,action:#selector(self.dismissFullScreenImage))

        newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        self.view.addSubview(newImageView)

    }

    func dismissFullScreenImage(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
    }


    /*
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

     if(segue.identifier == "findUserSegue")
     {
     var showFollowingTableViewController = segue.destination as! FollowUsersTableViewController


     showFollowingTableViewController.loggedInUser = self.loggedInUser as? FIRUser

     //            showFollowingTableViewController.followData = self.followData
     }
     else if(segue.identifier == "showFollowersTableViewController")
     {
     var showFollowersTableViewController = segue.destination as! ShowFollowersTableViewController
     showFollowersTableViewController.user = self.loggedInUser as? FIRUser

     }
     }
     */

}
```

And this is my Table View Cell code.

```
//
//  HomeViewTableViewCell.swift
//  Jalo
//
//  Created by Juan Carlos Estevez Rodriguez on 24/08/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 JC&C. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

open class HomeViewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var profilePic: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var handle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tweet: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tweetImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var ubic: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override open func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    open func configure(_ profilePic:String?,name:String,handle:String,tweet:String, ubi:String)
    {
        self.tweet.text = tweet
        self.handle.text = "@"+handle
        self.name.text = name
        self.ubic.text = ubi



        if((profilePic) != nil)
        {
            let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string:profilePic!)!)
            self.profilePic.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
        }
        else
        {
            self.profilePic.image = UIImage(named:"twitter")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error thrown when you return `self.Jalas.count`?

Comment: i have a feeling that you didnt set the table view delegate/data source methods

Comment: I added my entire code, i think i did but check it out jahahahaha @LucasChwe

Comment: looks like you got the methods going but i think you are missing setting the delegate and data source. something like self.homeTableView.delegate = self; and self.homeTableView.dataSource = self; in viewDidLoad should do

Comment: and i dont think you only want to insert 1 row, i think you are better off just calling reloadData instead of insertRows:

Answer (score 0):

This

```
self.homeTableView.beginUpdates()
self.homeTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:0,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
self.homeTableView.endUpdates()
```

Segment is what's most likely causing your problem. Won't be sure until you edit your question and add the exact error.

When you use `.insertRows()` in a UITableView, you need to make sure that the count in `numberOfRows inSection` method also changes accordingly. What you have here is just a mismatch between the number of rows returned by the delegate method and the actual number of rows. Make sure that when you use `.insertRows()` you return the new expected number of rows in the delegate method!

Comment: It's ok! We all have to start somewhere :-)
That error indicates what I suspected. You're simply returning a specific number of rows in a section that's different from what is actually there. So just make sure you add a new element into `self.Jalas` before using `.insertRows(at: ..., with: ...)` so that `self.Jalas.count` has the same number of rows in the table. They must match! If you don't get it, let me know so I can update my answer and add an example maybe

Comment: attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update that is the error that i'm getting. So... exactly what is what i have to do @ThunderStruct , sorry i'm quite new in swift